# What should i do to get the smallest of the sequence entered by the user?

Tags: c++

I am making a program that should reader the user's input until something non-numeric is enetered  by the user. I have to do this with vector. So the user has to define the the values of the elements and the size of the vector. The numVals should be intizialed as the amount of elements the user enters. The program should find the second smallest number of the sequence. So i tried to get first the smallest number, because that is easier. But give as input always zero instead of the minimum. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<limits>
#include<stdexcept>
using namespace std;

int main(){        
    unsigned int i;
    int numVals; 
    int min;        

    vector<int>sequence(numVals);       

    cout << "sequence: ";
    while (cin.good()){
       for (i=0; i<sequence.size(); ++i){        
            cin >> sequence.at(i);              
           }  
    }

    min =sequence.at(0);
    for (i=0; i<sequence.size();++i){
        if (sequence.at(i)< min){
            min=sequence.at(i);
        }
    }
    cout << min << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `vector<int>sequence(numVals);`, `numVals` is not initialized.

Comment: Let's start with the obvious. In order to find the minimum, you don't need to keep the whole sequence. Imagine someone is reading you a sequence of numbers over the phone and you have no paper or pen and the sequence is too long to remember. Can you still find the smallest number?

Comment: well... you don't need to iterate over all sequence. Initialize "min" with std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max. When you receive the input you can check with the last input. If you will do something with the vector, forget my ideia

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few issues with your code. The following code should do what you had in mind.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    int num;
    vector<int>sequence;

    cout << "sequence: ";
    while(cin >> num)
       sequence.push_back(num);

    int min = sequence.at(0);

    for (int n: sequence)
    {
        if (n < min)
          min = n;
    }

    cout << min << endl;
}
```

First of all, you have initialized the vector with an undefined size by not initializing `numVals`.

Secondly, `cin.good()` is used incorrectly.`cin.good()` gives the status of the last input. So in the case where it returns false, a zero input would have entered your sequence, which means the zero entry will always be the smallest!

EDIT: Refactored the implementation thanks to comments from @n.m.

Comment: No better than the original. `cin >> num` is the thing that makes cin go bad. Checking if cin is good *before* that buys you nothing whatsoever.

Comment: @n.m. I wouldn't say no better. There is a crucial difference. The original does not work, this one does. My intention wasn't to refactor or redesign the OP's code, was just to point out what was wrong and provide a quick working fix.

Comment: @n.m. Fixed it by not inserting at all when cin is bad.

Comment: It worked, for some lousy definition of "work". It passed a test, maybe. Now you are doing a counter-idiomatic double checking, which technically works but it would get your code fail a code review. Are you familiar with the `while (cin >> ...)` idiom?

Comment: @n.m. Like I said before, my intention had been to fix it with as few changes as possible. But you're right, in that half-hearted attempt at fixing your comment, I made it far worse. FWIW, here's a solution that (hopefully) goes all the way!

Comment: This is indeed much better ;)